# Range of python's random.random() from the standard library

Tags: python, random

Does python's random.random() ever return 1.0 or does it only return up until 0.9999..?

Comment: There's gold in them thar hills.  42 points (and counting) for a question about what random.random() returns.  <insert suitable exclamation>

Comment: Notice if you don't terminate your sequence 0.9999 it is actually equal to 1.0.

Comment: @ThomasAhle It's not.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Docs are here: http://docs.python.org/library/random.html

> ...random(), which
>   generates a random float uniformly in
>   the semi-open range [0.0, 1.0).

So, the return value will be greater than or equal to 0, and less than 1.0.

Comment: For an explanation of the bracket/parent range notation, look here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interval_(mathematics)#Terminology

Comment: I think Python's internal help system (as mentioned in another answer) is much more immediately accessible when you're programming in Python.  `help(random.random)` would've given the OP the information (s)he needed.

Comment: It's much better to link to the real documentation when you're writing on a webpage.

Answer (score 35):

```
>>> help(random.random)
Help on built-in function random:

random(...)
    random() -> x in the interval [0, 1).
```

That means 1 is excluded.

Comment: I like your answer best.  Python has a fantastic internal help system and people should be encouraged to use it.

Answer (score 12):

The other answers already clarified that 1 is not included in the range, but out of curiosity, I decided to look at the source to see precisely how it is calculated.

The CPython source can be found [here](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8eac75276e5b/Modules/_randommodule.c)

```
/* random_random is the function named genrand_res53 in the original code;
 * generates a random number on [0,1) with 53-bit resolution; note that
 * 9007199254740992 == 2**53; I assume they're spelling "/2**53" as
 * multiply-by-reciprocal in the (likely vain) hope that the compiler will
 * optimize the division away at compile-time.  67108864 is 2**26.  In
 * effect, a contains 27 random bits shifted left 26, and b fills in the
 * lower 26 bits of the 53-bit numerator.
 * The orginal code credited Isaku Wada for this algorithm, 2002/01/09.
 */
static PyObject *
random_random(RandomObject *self)
{
    unsigned long a=genrand_int32(self)>>5, b=genrand_int32(self)>>6;
    return PyFloat_FromDouble((a*67108864.0+b)*(1.0/9007199254740992.0));
}
```

So the function effectively generates `m/2^53` where `0 <= m < 2^53` is an integer. Since floats have 53 bits of precision normally, this means that on the range [1/2, 1), every possible float is generated. For values closer to 0, it skips some possible float values for efficiency but the generated numbers are uniformly distributed within the range. The largest possible number generated by `random.random` is precisely

0.99999999999999988897769753748434595763683319091796875

Comment: If the above C code is compiled with -fsingle-precision-constant, this could yield 1.0. See my answer for details

Answer (score 10):

Python's [`random.random`](http://docs.python.org/library/random.html) function returns numbers that are less than, but not equal to, `1`.

However, it can return `0`.

Comment: random() -> x in the interval [0, 1)
That is, including 0.

Comment: @telliott99: That's (almost) exactly what I said.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer not to rely on sci-fi math notation!

Comment: @Jørn Schou-Rode, I learned about open and closed intervals sometime in elementary to high-school.  I can't remember when.  People, especially programmers, should learn to understand them if they don't already.

Comment: @Omnifarious: it was so long time ago that i forgot about them and i actually thought that that was a typo in their docs

Answer (score 5):

From the code in Antimony's answers it is easy to see that random.random() never returns exactly 1.0 on platforms that have at least 53 bit mantissa for calculations involving constants not annotated with 'f' in C. That's the precision IEEE 754 prescribes and is standard today.

However, on platforms with lower precision, for example if Python is compiled with -fsingle-precision-constant for use on an embedded platform, adding b to a*67108864.0 can result in rounding up to 2^53 if b is close enough to 2^26 and this would mean that 1.0 is returned. Note that this happens regardless of what precision Python's PyFloat_FromDouble function uses.

One way to test for this would be to check a few hundred random numbers whether the 53rd bit is ever 1. If it is 1 at least once this proofs sufficient precision and you are fine. If not, rounding is the most likely explanation meaning that random.random() can return 1.0. It's of course possible that you were just unlucky. You can push the certainty as high as you want by testing more numbers.